# Ramda: rewriting to point free style

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js, pointfree, tacit-programming

I use the following function to send some data to a React component by wrapping it in a higher-order component:

```
import { equals, filter, isNil, prop, where } from 'ramda'

const example = getChapter => ownProps =>
  filter(
    where({
      sectionId: equals(prop('section', ownProps)),
      subsectionId: isNil,
      sub2sectionId: isNil,
      sub3sectionId: isNil
    }),
    prop('getContents', getChapter)
  )
```

I’m familiar with the concepts of functional programming, but still relatively new to the Ramda library. Now I’d like to rewrite this code using Ramda so that `ownProps` and `getChapter` can get eliminated, if only as an academic exercise.

It seems like I should eliminate `ownProps` first because of the order of the arguments? Although I’m not even sure of that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

PS. I’m aware that in the code above `ownProps.section` would be more readable and preferred to `prop('section', ownProps)`, ceteri paribus, but I expect that the `prop` function lies on the path to a point-free equivalent of the code above, hence their inclusion.

Comment: point-free style doesn't increase reusability. `x => f (x)` and point-free `f` are equivalent, but expressed with a different *style*. one is not "more reusable" than the other.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I updated the question.

Comment: Can you explain what the _purpose_ of this function is? I think that would be important to clarify. What is `ownProps`?

Comment: `ownProps` is an object containing the props supplied to a react component, for example for `<Content section={8}>` it would be `{ section: 8 }`. In this case, the `Content` component gets wrapped in a higher-order component which supplies its data. Because the `Content` component is used in multiple places, the data supplied to it differ, and the criteria for this are in the `where` function in the code given above. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that it will look quite bad and would be very far from best practices to make it entirely point-free. It will have to involve a number of steps. One step would be to _create_ the object you send into _where_ with R.assoc.

Comment: What do you mean with _because the functions are not commutative_? If you mean that you can't change the order of getChapter and ownProps in `example = getChapter => ownProps => ...` I think it is incorrect. I don't see why you would not be able to change it into `example = ownProps => getChapter => ...`

Comment: Whoops, my bad, you are correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Could** this be done?  Sure.  Here's one version:

```
const example2 = useWith(flip(filter), [prop('getContents'), pipe(
  prop('section'),
  equals,
  objOf('sectionId'),
  where,
  both(where({
    subsectionId: isNil,
    sub2sectionId: isNil,
    sub3sectionId: isNil
  }))
)])
```

The most unusual function in there is Ramda's [`useWith`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#useWith), which acts approximately like `useWith(f, [g, h])(x, y) ~> f(g(x, y), h(x, y))`.  This is not a standard functional language construct, only one that helped make point-free some functions that were difficult to do so.  It was mostly useful, though, before ES6/ES2015 became ubiquitous.

You can see this in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.25.0#?console.clear%28%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20getChapter%20%3D%20%7BgetContents%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%7Bid%3A%201%2C%20sectionId%3A%20%27foo%27%2C%20subsectionId%3A%201%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bid%3A%202%2C%20sectionId%3A%20%27bar%27%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bid%3A%203%2C%20sectionId%3A%20%27foo%27%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bid%3A%204%2C%20sectionId%3A%20%27baz%27%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bid%3A%205%2C%20sectionId%3A%20%27foo%27%7D%0A%5D%7D%0A%0Aconst%20example%20%3D%20getChapter%20%3D%3E%20ownProps%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20filter%28%0A%20%20%20%20where%28%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20sectionId%3A%20equals%28prop%28%27section%27%2C%20ownProps%29%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20subsectionId%3A%20isNil%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20sub2sectionId%3A%20isNil%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20sub3sectionId%3A%20isNil%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20prop%28%27getContents%27%2C%20getChapter%29%0A%20%20%29%0A%0Aconsole.log%28example%28getChapter%29%28%7Bsection%3A%20%27foo%27%7D%29%29%0A%0Aconst%20example2%20%3D%20useWith%28flip%28filter%29%2C%20%5Bprop%28%27getContents%27%29%2C%20pipe%28%0A%20%20prop%28%27section%27%29%2C%0A%20%20equals%2C%0A%20%20objOf%28%27sectionId%27%29%2C%0A%20%20where%2C%0A%20%20both%28where%28%7B%0A%20%20%20%20subsectionId%3A%20isNil%2C%0A%20%20%20%20sub2sectionId%3A%20isNil%2C%0A%20%20%20%20sub3sectionId%3A%20isNil%0A%20%20%7D%29%29%0A%29%5D%29%0A%0Aconsole.log%28example2%28getChapter%29%28%7Bsection%3A%20%27foo%27%7D%29%29%3B%0A)**.

---

**Should** you do this?  Well, you said it's an academic exercise, so perhaps.  But I find this much less readable than the original.  This seems to me useful only as a way to learn some of the features of Ramda.  I wouldn't put it into production.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Scott's answer this is another possible variant:

```
useWith(
  flip(filter),
  [
    prop('getContents'),
    pipe(
      prop('section'),
      equals,
      assoc('sectionId', R.__, {
        subsectionId: isNil,
        sub2sectionId: isNil,
        sub3sectionId: isNil
      }),
      where
    )
  ])
```

And if you call it with the order of the arguments reversed you don't need the `flip` on the `filter`.